# Keep emphasis on click with echarts graph

Tags: javascript, html, echarts

I have a graph chart made using echarts. When I hover on the edges, it displays some behavior set on the emphasis option. there is any way i can have this behavior happening when I click one of the edges ?

Emphasis code :

```
emphasis: {
            lineStyle: {
              width: 5,
              color: "#555555"
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myChart.on('click', (params) => {
  if (params.dataType === 'edge') { 
    /* you can check params to look for what you want to pick */
    myChart.dispatchAction({
        /* HighLight type */
        type: 'focusNodeAdjacency',
        /* OffLight type if you need */
        // type: 'unfocusNodeAdjacency',
        /* Positioning the series with seriesId/seriesIndex/seriesName */
        seriesIndex: 0,
        /* Positioning the node with dataIndex */
        dataIndex: params.dataIndex
    });
  }
})
```